# Change ID number feed

Tags: list

I was wondering whether it's possible to change the ID feed for a list. We're migrating an older system to SharePoint and the customer requested that the ID's of the items stay the same in SharePoint. In the old system, the ID column is a regular autoincrement integer, same as the SharePoint ID. There are gaps in the numbering.

So what I'm looking for is two things:
- Is it possible to specify the ID on insert? I assume it's not 
- Is it possible to change the ID feed for a list? Is that being stored somewhere or is it recalculated every time (can't imagine that)

I already thought of creating empty items and immediately deleting those again as a workaround, but I want to be able to revert the ID feed too after testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible mange the ID numbering of the list items.  It is an autonumber feed with no reliable way to seed it or remove any of the gaps.